# jquery chosen update not working after ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have some issue with jquery chosen (ver 1.5.1). In my laravel project I have view with modal. In view is select with alreay some list. User using modal with form, can add position to the table from which I wanna update select list and update chosen. My code:
View:

```php
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-3 text-right" for="car">Klient: <a href="/car/create" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="">(Add car)</a></label>
        <div class="col-9">
            {!! Form::select('cari', $car, null, ['class'=>'form-control form-control-sm form-control-chosen', 'id' => 'client', 'placeholder' => 'Chose car']) !!}
            {!! $errors->first('cari', '<strong><p style="color:red;" class="help-block">:message</p></strong>') !!}
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#client").chosen({
                    no_results_text: 'Missing sorry.',
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">add new car:</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col response-client">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('car') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">car danem: </label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="car" type="text" id="newcar">
                        {!! $errors->first('car', '<strong><p style="color:red;" class="help-block">:message</p></strong>') !!}
                    </div>
</div>
                    <button type="submit" id="add-car" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">{{ __('save') }}<i class="icon-floppy"></i></button>
       </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

script code

```js
   $('#add-car').click(function(){
       var car = $('#newcar').val();                                    

      $.ajax({
     url:"{{ url('cars/carNew') }}",
     method:"POST",
   data:{car:car, _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}"},

     success:function(result)
     {
      if(result.result > 0)
       {
              NewCar();
       }
       else
       {
            $("#msg").html("Error can't add new car!");
            $("#msg").fadeOut(2000);
       }
      },
      error:function(xhr)
      {
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
     })                                 

   });

                                function NewCar()
                                {                                    
                                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                                    $('#client').empty();                                   

                                    $.ajax({
                                        url:"{{ url('umowy/klienci') }}",
                                        method:"POST",
                                        data:{ _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}"},

                                        success:function(result)
                                        {
                                            $("#client").append('<option>Chose car</option>');
                                            if(result)
                                            {
                                                $.each(result,function(key,value){
                                                    $('#client').append($("<option/>", {
                                                        value: key,
                                                        text: value
                                                    }));
                                                });
                                            }

                                            $('#client').trigger('chosen:updated');                                         

                                        },
                                        error:function(xhr)
                                        {
                                            console.log(xhr.responseText);
                                        }

                                    });

                                }
                            });
```

Everything works very well except that `$('#client').trigger('chosen:updated');`. Nothing happen no errors. I'm not sure if I'm doing everything right? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Hi, `result` has correct values ?

Comment: yes, it returns that what I expect